# how to increase or decrease common emitter amplifier Av gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, transformer, power-electronics

common emitter amplifier (BJT), With components, transistor hfe 300, AC signal 10 milli volts, 1KHz, Vcc 12,

RB 1 = 15K, RB 2 = 2.2K, RC = 10, RE = 830 ohms, (the Av gain for this circuit is 12,) how can the Av can be reduced to 10 ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean RC=10k?

Comment: First understand what determines Av in the existing circuit. (Hint : @glen_geek is probably right).

Comment: Just add a load to the output. ;) Easy to reduce Av to 10 with the right loading! (Happens all too often, too.)

Comment: post a schematic I don't know what RB1 and RB2, I'm thinking its a voltage divider base bias some way. but what is where? Draw it plz...

Comment: @drtechno It wouldn't work if RB1 is the divider resistor with one end at ground, so it has to be RB2 on that side of the divider. Also, RC cannot be 10 as shown in the question, obviously. But yes, a schematic answers more questions.

Comment: yes, a schematic is needed. RC is 10? if it isn't a typo, its the emitter resistor.

Comment: @drtechno I'm pretty sure an RC of 10 k was meant, because \$\frac{10\:\text{k}}{830}\approx 12\$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the schematic you ***should*** have added to your question:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8uArGm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You are supposed to know how to compute the voltage gain for such a circuit.

You should also be able to quickly realize that:

$$I_B\approx \frac{V_{CC}\frac{R_{B_2}}{R_{B_1}+R_{B_2}}-V_{BE}}{\left(R_{B_1}\mid\mid R_{B_2}\right) +R_E\cdot\left(\beta+1\right)}$$

From this and an assumption for a moment of \$V_{BE}=700\:\text{mV}\$, you can estimate \$I_B\approx 3.32\:\mu\text{A}\$, \$I_C\approx 995\:\mu\text{A}\$, and \$I_E\approx 998\:\mu\text{A}\$.

Therefore, \$V_C\approx 2.05\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_E\approx 830\:\text{mV}\$.

It might not be saturated. But it probably is because I may have over-estimated \$V_{BE}\$.

For example, suppose \$V_{BE}=650\:\text{mV}\$ (which it might actually be.) Then I'd find \$V_C\approx 1.45\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_E\approx 880\:\text{mV}\$ and I'd now be pretty certain that the device was slightly saturated (which is a problem, given that this is the quiescent state without any input yet.)

So the design already looks problematic. Reducing the gain to 10 seems like an opportunity to semi-fix this "near or slightly" saturated situation. (It won't be a complete fix. But at least it might pull it out of near saturation.) It also tells me which resistor I may change and which resistor I had better not change (if I can only change one of them.)

Should be obvious.

---

As it is closed now, and also since it has been some time, try \$R_C=8.2\:\text{k}\Omega\$, \$R_E=820\:\Omega\$, \$R_{B_1}=68\:\text{k}\Omega\$, and \$R_{B_2}=6.8\:\text{k}\Omega\$.